# .frm .MYD .MYI 1 file have 3 different extension

Tags: mysql

Why some table have 3 types of files and some doesn't.

If i remove one of them what will happen

If I have one table call admin.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_assert` (
  `assert_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Assert ID',
  `assert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Assert Type',
  `assert_data` text COMMENT 'Assert Data',
  PRIMARY KEY (`assert_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Assert Table';
```

How can I encode this .sql file to .frm .MYD .MYI extensions manually?

Comment: .myd, .myi, .frm are extensions for MyISAM tables. For creating files with these extensions you should change `ENGINE=MyISAM` in your script. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @EvgenyShavlyugin No, I would like to find the easiest way to put my big database to that FOLDER.. My notepad ++ get hanged when I try to open my database. Glad.. if I could put them from that folder and open it from phpmyadmin panel to make edit some of that...

Comment: Then you should edit your original question as in it's unclear in it's current form. The simplest way is to copy your files to destination folder and create symbolic links.

Comment: You have to import the sql file.`mysql -u <user> -p <database> < your_big_database_sql.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't covert this sql file to these three files manually.

These three formats- .frm .MYD .MYI  represent that the table is in MyISAM.
It represents structure file, data file and index file.

The rest of tables are in some another engine probably Innodb that have .ibd and frm files.

You can convert your sql file to these three files by:

First create the table.
Alter the table by command=>  ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE='MYISAM';
Then you can see three files..